# expo image preview after choose not working

Tags: react-native, expo

If the user choose an image, then I get the local Uri. If I create an Image component with source uri and put the local uri in there it doesnt work. But Why?

Home.js

```
  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [1, 1],
      quality: 1
    });
    
    if(!result.cancelled) {
      let localUri = result.uri;
      let filename = localUri.split('/').pop();

      let match = /\.(\w+)$/.exec(filename);
      let type = match ? `image/${match[1]}` : `image`;


      setImagePreview(localUri);
    }
  };
```

Also Home.js but other code snippet:

```
<Image source={{uri: imagePreview}}/>
```

€: this is the local uri:

```
file:/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/UNVERIFIED-192.168.0.54-gamezone/ImagePicker/b5c20467-4ad1-4bdf-aa74-8aad82e2c075.jpg
```

Comment: show your `<Image />` component.? There's no problem in your `Home.js`..There must be some error in `<Image />` component.

Comment: Its the standard offical react component I didnt create a own Image component.And I get no errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

```
<Image source={{uri: imagePreview}}/>
```

With this

```
<Image source={{uri: imagePreview}} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
```

You need to provide `Dimensions` to the `image`